# Show progress value for volley file download

Tags: android, download, android-volley

I need to show the progress of file download in percentage.

Currently I am using **Volley** library. I use `InputStreamVolleyRequest` class to make the download request and `BufferedOutputStream` to read/write the file.

How can I show the progress update in the most efficient manner?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are using `InputStreamVolleyRequest`, I hope you have written the following code or something similar as well:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        if (response!=null) {

            String content =request.responseHeaders.get("Content-Disposition")
                    .toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(content, "=");
            String[] arrTag = st.toArray();

            String filename = arrTag[1];
            filename = filename.replace(":", ".");
            Log.d("DEBUG::FILE NAME", filename);

            try{
                long lenghtOfFile = response.length;

                InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);

                File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(path, filename);
                map.put("resume_path", file.toString());
                BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();

                output.close();
                input.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you have already done this, putting a progress bar is easy.
get `ProgressDialog` object and initialise as shown below:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity Context here);
progressDialog.setTitle("Any Title here");
progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading in Progress...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
progressDialog.show();
```

Then just modify the while loop as shown below:

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    output.write(data, 0, count);
    progress = (int)total*100/file_length;
    progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
}
```

Try this and let me know.

However let me also inform you that Volley is not suitable for heavy download. Rather I suggest you to use `DownloadManager` or Apache's `HttpClient` or even `AsyncTask`. They are easier to use and probably better for this purpose.

Comment: isnt `onResponse` called after the file is completely downloaded?

Comment: yes, in fact this doesn't work on my side. Plus the class InputStreamVolleyRequest is taken from an example that it's not referred anywhere in the question or the answer.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. onResponse(), we have already downloaded the file, it will show file writing disk progress.

Comment: Does volley support resume support in case of network fluctuations?

Answer (score 0):

I am using progress bar with Httpclient so if you want to do progress then my suggestion is use HTTP client so that you can make exactly you want

Here is Link :
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Hope this will help you ! Cheers !

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question.